# Magento 1.9 - What is wrong in my Event Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I just want to display my event name :

> app\etc\modules\Gta_RestrictProductByCountry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>

    <modules>

        <Gta_RestrictProductByCountry>

            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>

        </Gta_RestrictProductByCountry>

    </modules>

</config>
```

> app\code\local\Gta\RestrictProductByCountry\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_RestrictProductByCountry>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_RestrictProductByCountry>
    </modules>
    <global> 
        <models>
            <gta_restrictproductbycountry>
                <class>Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model</class>
            </gta_restrictproductbycountry>
        </models> 
     </global> 
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <!-- <sales_order_place_before> -->
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <gta_restrictproductbycountry_observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>gta_restrictproductbycountry/observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </gta_restrictproductbycountry_observer>
                </observers>
            <!-- </sales_order_place_before>       -->
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>      
        </events>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

> app\code\local\Gta\RestrictProductByCountry\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
class Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model_Observer
{
    public function cartevent($Observer)
    {

        $cart_product_check = $Observer->getEvent();
        Mage::log($cart_product_check->getName(), null, 'orderproduct.log',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue - i mean event is not working ?

Comment: Yes, after placed an order 'orderproduct.log' not generated in var/log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done with below changes,

```
<frontend>
        <events>
            <!-- <sales_order_place_before> -->
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model_Observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            <!-- </sales_order_place_before>       -->
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>      
        </events>
    </frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try update below code :

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <gta_restrictproductbycountry_observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>gta_restrictproductbycountry/observer</class>
                        <method>cartevent</method>
                    </gta_restrictproductbycountry_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

> app\code\local\Gta\RestrictProductByCountry\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
class Gta_RestrictProductByCountry_Model_Observer
{
    public function cartevent($Observer)
    {

        $cart_product_check = $Observer->getEvent();
        Mage::log($cart_product_check->getName(), null, 'orderproduct.log',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls check with my updated post, still 'orderproduct.log' not generated under var/log @Anas Mansuri

Comment: can you please replace with - <gta_restrictproductbycountry_observer>

Comment: Still no luck, orderproduct.log not generated.

Comment: pls check with my updated post

Comment: please check i update my answer